# Is it possible to calculate key(0) and key(1) of ZipCrypto using key(2)?

Tags: rc4, crc

Here is Zipcrypto decryption algorithm:

```
Key(0) <- 305419896
Key(1) <- 591751049
Key(2) <- 878082192

update_keys(char):
    Key(0) <- crc32(key(0),char)
    Key(1) <- Key(1) + (Key(0) & 000000ffH)
    Key(1) <- Key(1) * 134775813 + 1
    Key(2) <- crc32(key(2),key(1) >> 24)
end update_keys

loop for i <- 0 to length(password)-1
    update_keys(password(i))
end loop
```

What if knew only Key(2) after complete execution of the above code, Is it possible to perform calculations to obtain correct two keys (Key(0),Key(1)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we don't know anything about password, no we can't compute `Key(0)` or/and `Key(1)` from `Key(2)` at the end of the algorithm.

Argument: for long-enough random password, `Key(0) ∥ Key(1) ∥ Key(2)` is about uniformly random.